# How to validate servertimestamp is less than a certain value in Firebase itself?

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-security

I need help with this Firebase rule, I have this child where I store a timestamp

[image]

And I need to only allow writing to another location at the firebase when the server timestamp is less than that stored on the Date->date child.
I am not sure how to do it, in write or validate, or how to get the rule to read certain value in Firebase itself.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "test":{
                 ".read" : false,
          this-->".write": "now < root.child('date\Date')",
       or this-->".validate": "now < root.child('date\Date')"
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I am able to read from a location now, but the problem is casting the value for comarison.
I tried (int) (Integer) parseInt() Number() and they all failed

Am I on the right track or should be done differently?

**UPDATE 2**
I managed to write an acceptable rule -that doesn't produce an error-, but it doesn't work, here it is

```
{
    "rules": {
        "test":{
          ".write": "now < root.child('date/Date').val()",
          ".read" : false
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE 3**

Actually it didn't work well, I think it was comparing a number coming from 'now' function to a string coming form the root.child.val, so the rule was always false.

I managed to work around it, putting the solution here just in case someone else needs it

```
    "rules": {
        "test":{
          ".write": "now + ' ' < root.child('date/Date').val() + ' '",
          ".read" : read
        }
    }
```

So Basically I added the (+ ' ') to now to convert it to string, and added the same to val just to make both strings in comparison the same lengh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Security Rules can read data in your Firebase database. You can check against the timestamp if you combine using the `now` variable with the `root` variable.

```
{
    "rules": {
        "test":{
          ".write": "now < root.child('date').child('Date').val()",
          ".read" : "now < root.child('date').child('Date').val()"
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your code, you need to listen to the cancel callback:

```
var ref = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>/test");
ref.on('value', function(snap) {
  console.log(snap.val());
}, function(error) {
   // if permission is denied the error will log here
  console.error(error);
});
```

[Check out the Firebase API reference for more info.](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html)

Also, using the Simulator in the Firebase App Dashboard should help you test your rules:

[image]

Comment: Thanks again, you are being very helpful, really appreciate it. Are rules not applied when using Console? I still can write to the location when I use Chrome console even if I set it to write : false.

Comment: Ah, you're writing from the console with your Firebase App Dashboard open. Yes, rules are not applied there because you are an admin. The Firebase App Dashboard is a web app that has admin rights to the Firebase database. When you use the console and create a ref, you get the local rights of the web app which is admin. Try accessing the data in incognito mode or use the simulator.

Comment: Just though of letting you know how it went, updated the question above. I think there must be a better solution, but this worked, for now ;)

Comment: I work on Firebase, and I can tell you that this is the most straightforward solution.

Comment: I meant better one than adding the (+ ' ' ) to now to convert it to string for comparison.